# How to Stick a div to the right hand side of the iPad viewport

Tags: jquery, ipad, screen, viewport

[image: Sample of what I'm trying to do]

When you click the closed div, it should animate to the center of the screen.

When you click the opened div, it should animate back to the edge of the viewport.

The parent (like the body for example) should be 1024px.

**Code preview:**

http://jsbin.com/uhuxen/2

Comment: Yes, maybe I should clarify. I'll edit above.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery animate to change the left property.

```
$('#edge_dweller').click( function(event){
  $('#edge_dweller').animate({
      right: (50) + '%',
    marginRight: -100 + 'px'
  }, 5000);
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

And this would be the code to close and open:

```
$('#edge_dweller').click( function(event){
  if ($('#edge_dweller').css('right') == '50%')
    $('#edge_dweller').animate({
      right: (0) + '%',
      marginRight: 0 + 'px'
    }, 5000);
  else
    $('#edge_dweller').animate({
      right: (50) + '%',
      marginRight: -100 + 'px'
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: there's more to it than that: 
http://jsbin.com/uhuxen/3

it's a matter of getting it to 50% of the page then subtracting 50% of the div's width as well.